# Save matrices of a loop iteration in one matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, save

I have a loop that makes a 100x10 matrix in every iteration, i want to save all the matrices of this loop in one matrix. assuming that i have a loop with 5 iterations, i want to have a 500x10 matrix in the end (after appending all the 5 matrices of the loop).

```
for ii = 1:numfiles
str = fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});
file_id = fopen(str);
data = fread (file_id)';
....
s = zeros (100, 10);
%doing some stuffs
save('s_all', 's','-append');
end
```

I have used `save('s_all', 's','-append');` 
but it doesn't append the matrices. How can i do that?

Comment: when you mean `save` you mean "create a variable with all matrices" or "save it to memory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the document:

> `save(filename,variables,'-append')` adds new variables to an existing file. If a variable already exists in a MAT-file, then save overwrites it with the value in the workspace.

Therefore, `save` just adds a variable at the end of the `.mat` file, not to add at the end of a variable inside the `.mat` file.

## Solution 1:

To write matrix into the file it would be better using `dlmwrite` likes the following:

```
dlmwrite(filename,s,'-append');
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).
In a complete case you can do:

```
filename = 's_all.csv';   
for ii = 1:numfiles
    str = fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});
    file_id = fopen(str);
    data = fread (file_id)';
    % ...
    s = zeros (100, 10);
    %doing some stuffs
    dlmwrite(filename,s,'-append');
end
```

## Solution 2:

The other solution is each time load the specified matrix, then attach the matrices into it, and then append to the file.

```
filename = 'file.mat';   
% suppose originMatrix is an empty matrix or a matrix with columns size 10
for ii = 1:numfiles
    load(filename,'originMatrix');
    s = zeros (100, 10);
    %doing some stuffs
    originMatrix = [originMatrix; s];
    save(filename,'originMatrix','-append');
end
```

Comment: I just want to save it in a .mat file.

Comment: so you should append them into a matrix. You can't append data into a variable in the `.mat` file.

Comment: I see, so i should create a Matrix first then put all of them into it, right?

Comment: This append as you write, appends matrices to the mat file, not to a variable of the mat. The only problem for your case is load origin matrix `o`, then appending matrices into the origin. For example, each time load 'o' then attach the `o1` like `o = [o;o1]`. And loop on this for each matrices which you want.

Comment: @lighting yes. exactly.